# Save dropdown list value to php session

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a drop down list that is populated by data from mysql db, im trying to save the selected value in a session variable but im not sure how to write this (where the *** are)? And does it need to be posted to server side eve though its all in php?

```
    <?php
$servername1 = "localhost";
$username1 = "root";
$password1 = "";
$dbname1 = "gpdb1";
$conn1 = new mysqli($servername1, $username1, $password1, $dbname1);
if ($conn1->connect_error) {
die("connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
}
$sql2 = "SELECT DoctorID, Title, Surname FROM doctors";
$result2 = $conn1->query($sql2);
echo "<select name='doctor' value=''><option>Select a Doctor</option>";
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
foreach($result2 as $row2) 
{echo "<option value=".$row2['DoctorID'].">".$row2['Title']."     ".$row2['Surname']."</option>"; 
}
}echo "</select>";
$_SESSION['selected']=***;
if (isset($_SESSION['selected'])){
echo $SESSION['selected'];}
?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What is this line? echo "<select name='doctor' value=''>Select a Doctor</option>";

Comment: it starts with select and ends with option?!

Comment: i believe it creates the dropdown list, just a standard html tag i think, i just took it from a general example but it works

Comment: i never noticed that lol, because the close </select> is after the statement but the actual dropdown list is working fine, probably should be a <option> before the value..

Comment: <select ...>...</option> bad example ...

Comment: Yes, fixed that lol,

Comment: sorry, updated the example, silly mistake although doesnt affect the problem

Answer (score 0):

First, I advise you to indent your code, for better readability !

The HTML attribute "value" in your  tag isn't useful, you can remove it.

And then, it is not useful to control your session field with isset() since you're setting it just above.

I think that you just need to control if the given value in the post field is correct.

The line you are looking for is :

```
$_SESSION['selected'] = $_POST['doctor'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, im new with this so always welcome. This is what i have seen in other examples but the variable `$_POST['doctor']` is not being recognised, I thought this was becuase the value is not technically being posted its just being set? not sure if what i just write is right though lol?

Comment: Are you using a <form> tag with "method" attribute set to POST ? I think you've forgotten it in your html :) !

And then, as pointed above, don't forget to call the function session_start(); in the beginning of your script !

Comment: Its ok ive just posted the value using javascript to the php server, wanted to try and do it without this but it works so its good enough, thanks though guys

Answer (score 0):

First enable your error reporting:

```
<?php
// Turn off error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report runtime errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
```

Then you should set all relevant tags in your html code properly, but for this to work you need "name" tag on select element. Then make sure that your html code when script is executed looks something like this(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="do_stuff.php">
<select name="doctor">
  <!-- your loop generates this part -->

  <option value="doc1">Doctor 1</option>
  <option value="doc2">Doctor 2</option>
  <option value="doc3">Doctor 3</option>
  <option value="doc4">Doctor 4</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

In your php file you should check for `$_POST['doctor']` after you check if form is submitted. Then like @Kern pointed set `$_SESSION['selected']` with appropriate variable.

For easier debugging use [var_dump($variable)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) which will help you most of the times to find trivial errors. So var_dump($_POST) at the beginning of the script to find out what happening.